# Cron job running in background with waitress in python:3.7.6-buster (debian) container

Tags: debian, docker, cron

I'm trying to run a cron job within a container alongside a waitress http server.
No matter what I do I can't seem to get cron to start automatically within the container...

Here's my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.7.6-buster
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python3-dev cron
WORKDIR /home/user

COPY . .
RUN echo "* * * * * root echo hello >> /home/log.log 2>&1\n" > /etc/cron.d/task
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/task
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/task
RUN touch /home/log.log
CMD cron

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT [ "waitress-serve" ]
CMD [ "-call", "main:main" ]
```

I've tried also starting the cron service, but when the container is up, `service cron status` shows the following:

`[FAIL] cron is not running ... failed!`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Containers don't have an init system, which means no one is starting the cron daemon.

Comment: So how can I get cron to start up automatically?

Comment: You can't get it to start automatically. There is more or less nothing automatic in Docker. So if you really want it to run, you need to do something with your entrypoint. Instead of calling waitress, instead start a script or small init or something that manages cron and waitress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Docker vs VMs]

You're not starting cron anywhere in dockerfile. Also containers don't use init.d and systemd, they aren't virtual machines and they don't have own systemd/init.d. That's why you see following error:

```
[FAIL] cron is not running ... failed!
```

My solution is to write simple bash script (or just change whole CMD) which starts crond and other things you want to work in the background.
Example:

```
crond -P -n -s && waitress-serve -call main:main && tail -f /home/log.log
```

Command *tail -f* is here to prevent from exiting your container instantly. Flags *-P -n -s* are for inhereting path from environment (-P), sending job output to syslog which is optional and it is just my preference (-s) and working in the background (-n).

Then just copy that script and change your CMD to:

```
CMD script.sh
```

Also add this to your dockerfile. This is mandatory for *-n* flag.

```
RUN sed -i '/session    required   pam_loginuid.so/c\#session    required   pam_loginuid.so' /etc/pam.d/crond
```

I think this should work now. If you'll encounter problems just hit me up with comment. This is my first solution here so please be patient :D